# How to run Windows Phone 8 emulator with Windows 8 basic ver installed?

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-phone-8, 64-bit

My laptop supports all the hardware requirements for running windows phone 8 sdk.
It has Windows 8 basic and not the Pro version.I have enabled Intel Virtual technology in the BIOS.But,Hyper-v client is not available in the windows features to activate Virtual machine.

Is there any way/possibility to run Windows Phone 8 sdk emulator and tools with Windows 8 basic OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install a Pro version of Windows 8 in order to run the emulator. I think you can install the SDK, as far as your Windows 8 is a 64bit version, and develop with vs2012 and the SDK, but you need to use a device for testing.

If your Windows 8 edition isn't a 64bits one, you can't install even the SDK to develop.

Comment: My Windows 8 basic edition is a 64-bit version.I could install the sdk but it showed a warning after the installation to enable Hyper-v client.

Comment: Can I install Hyper-V server 2012 and can make run Windows 8 sdk emulator ?
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/hyper-v-server/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is such a terrible answer, the Win8 Standard edition comes in 64-bit and the SDK installation DOES NOT inform you that it will require Win8 Pro for the emulator. There is no "real" reason why you can't use the Standard edition except for Microsoft wanting you to upgrade to Pro.

Comment: I recently decided to invest my time in learning how to create Windows Universal apps on my home PC and was surprised when I saw this limitation. Its such a waste to not allow indie developers to emulate Windows Phone with the basic version of Windows 8, 8.1. As I want to develop such apps in order to enhance Microsoft's platform adding such limitation after I have paid for my Home edition is not a good way to bring developers to a platform.